# java google drive API unable to download binary file

Tags: java, google-api, download, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have working code to list the files in my Google Drive folder containing binary files but I'm getting an error when trying to download:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/download/drive/v3/files/1udFizffA_0M4jSUBJbDI6uNVdPVhdymW?alt=media
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "alt",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.",
    "reason" : "fileNotDownloadable"
  } ],
  "message" : "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files."
}
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
Drive.Files f = driveService.files();
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
Drive.Files.Get get = f.get(file.getId());
httpResponse = get.executeMedia();
```

I also tried export using:

```
httpResponse = f.export(file.getId(),"application/octet-stream").executeMedia();
```

which didn't work either.

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [file.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#response) method does return the file data, however only for binary file types. that is what this error message its telling you.

> Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().get(fileId)
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

All other file types those being google docs, google sheets. check this page for more: [mimetype](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)

Need to be exported from the google mime type to a standard mime type. If you check the [manage-downloads#java](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#java) page you will find a documented example of how to use this method.

```
String fileId = "1ZdR3L3qP4Bkq8noWLJHSr_iBau0DNT4Kli4SxNc2YEo";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
driveService.files().export(fileId, "application/pdf")
    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

The trick with this method is to ensure you are setting the correct [mimetype](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)